# Were R.A. Salvatore's works inspired by real world D&D campaigns?

Tags: inspiration, legend-of-drizzt, r-a-salvatore

I have been reading the Legend of Drizzt series by R. A. Salvatore.  I am currently half way through Stream of Silver, which is in book two of the collection.  While reading this, I noticed that it almost reads like a novelization of a dungeons and dragons campaign.

If we assume that the main party, Drizzt and his group, are played by the players, then their interactions make a lot more sense.  In a campaign, it's sometimes common for players to rarely actually talk to each other in character, as these characters do.

Extending that assumption, every other character is an NPC (non-player character), and it makes more sense that they actually interact more, having had their story fleshed out by a caring dungeon master.

Also, the fights the characters have gotten into are reminiscent of fights characters in a game would get into, having one fight shortly follow another.

So, to me, there's a lot of evidence of these books being heavily influenced by the game.

Has R. A. Salvatore ever come out as stating that he based the book/s on any dungeons and dragon campaigns, either one's he has played in or otherwise?

Comment: I have no idea about Salvatore, but I'm pretty sure Gary Gygax did this for his Gord the Rogue novels.

Comment: Nicely downvoted. Answer deleted. It's based on the campaign _setting_ btw.

Comment: Yesss! More readers for the Salvatore god! And Best Sellers for his throne!
I know this is absolutely answerable "yes".  I need to dig up the sources.

Comment: @Bookeater yeah, I know it's set in the forgotten realms campaign setting.  my wording might be ambiguous, I meant were there any games of dnd that he played that inspired the stories he wrote.

Comment: Are you referring to _modules_?

Comment: @Bookeater no... I mean, were there any games of dnd, where he sat down at a table and played, or watched other people play (for example, acquisitions inc or critical role, albeit these are new compared to the books), that he then used as inspiration for how he wrote the books

Comment: It was all research & reading & writing, and no gaming at all as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[In this AMA-thread on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/IAmA/comments/2dck4v/hello_there_im_ra_salvatore_a_fantasy_author_for/cjo71qf/), we find the questions

> I want to know, where do you draw your inspiration from? Do you write about games you've played/ran, or is it straight from your head?

To which R.A. Salvatore answers

> Straight from my head, which is a jumble of everything around me: the people I meet, the stories I hear, the music I hear, the sights and sounds of life.
>
> Writers take it all in, chew it up into little pieces, and spit it back out, hopefully in entertaining ways.

Which I would take to mean that while some of the stories he's heard may have been told in DnD campaigns, it doesn't seem like they are a major inspiration for him.